# accessing a variable inside a closure from another function with swift

Tags: swift, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

I am trying to create an app that lists certain services where users can rate each of the services. The rating from each server is saved in firebase database. I am able to retrieve all the ratings and calculate averages using the following function:

```
func observeStars() {

    let placesRef = Database.database().reference().child("Review")

    placesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
let toId = snapshot.key
       var total: Double = 0.0
        var average: Double = 0.0
        placesRef.child(toId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

       let count = snapshot.childrenCount

        for childOfPlace in snapshot.children {

            let childOfPlaceSnap = childOfPlace as! DataSnapshot

            let dict = childOfPlaceSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let val = dict["STAR"] as! Double

            total += val

            }
             average = total/Double(count)
           print(average)


        })

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

As you can see, the average is printed within 2 consecutive closures inside the function. However, I am having trouble using these average values in another function in a separate swift file, so I can use it to show the average ratings in each tableViewcell representing each service. My big question is how do I bring the calculated average value outside of the observeStars() function and use it somewhere else? Any input would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
var average: Double = 0.0

func observeStars() {

let placesRef = Database.database().reference().child("Review")

placesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    let toId = snapshot.key
    var total: Double = 0.0

    placesRef.child(toId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let count = snapshot.childrenCount

    for childOfPlace in snapshot.children {

        let childOfPlaceSnap = childOfPlace as! DataSnapshot

        let dict = childOfPlaceSnap.value as! [String: Any]
        let val = dict["STAR"] as! Double

        total += val

        }
       self.average = total/Double(count)
       print(average)


    })

}, withCancel: nil)

}
```

Comment: I tried moving the 'var average: Double = 0.0' line outside of the function, but when I put 'print(average)' in viewDidLoad, the console shows 0.0